# Is there any PDF Reader that support both searching through opened tabs and navigating with vim binding?

Tags: pdf, pdf-viewer, pdf-editor

I have the need to open many PDFs at one time. In this situation, the name of each tab is truncated so many that I can't see the location of my expected tab.

Is there any PDF reader that can search by the tabs name and switch to the selected tabs?

Also, I would like to navigate with vim binding (mostly with `j` and `k`) when reading. [Okular](https://okular.kde.org) supports this kind of navigation but it doesn't support searching tabs.

Answer (score 0):

## Chromium (or Chrome) and hypothes.is

With Chromium you can search for titles in open tabs. I opened 50 tabs (local PDF) - 125 MB in one shot. I added more tabs by dragging and dropping on the window.

[hypothes.is](https://web.hypothes.is/) require an account. This free and open source project is a system which allows annotation of web pages and PDF. You can run it on local files if you check an option. First you have to create a private group if you want to keep your notes private (you have to select the group in MY GROUPS - than it should keep this as default). The annotations will be on the cloud (with the advantages and the inconveniences). There is a search page for annotations and an API. You can also take notes.

I think Okular save the highlights in the PDF. Don't know if you can search in all annotations. Chromium use more CPU than Okular. I rendered all PDF in Chromium, maybe you could lazy load them.

I made this Bookmarklet to load a PDF with hypothes.is menu in case the original button doesn't work.
Where `bjfhmglciegochdpefhhlphglcehbmek` is the identification [in the store](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/hypothesis-web-pdf-annota/bjfhmglciegochdpefhhlphglcehbmek).

`javascript:(function(){f='chrome-extension://bjfhmglciegochdpefhhlphglcehbmek/pdfjs/web/viewer.html?file='+window.location.href;location.href=f;})()`

You can annotate, take a note or highlight.

[image: Search in titles] [image: Notes]

## Firefox

In my opinion, the search in tabs in Firefox is better than in Chromium. You can search `bio co` (for **Co**mputational **bio**logy) and it will show you the corresponding tab. In Chromium you can add an extension for a better search than the default. Firefox doesn't allow extensions to run on PDF. You can bookmark a PDF page (it add .pdf#page=7 at the end of the path), however it will not be associated with the original. You can use use the arrows (left, right, up and down) or  j and k.

For searching in all open tabs titles (PDF and HTML) in Firefox, you only have to type `%` . Percent sign followed by a space in the address bar.

Comment: There are also some extensions to support tab searching in browser which is more convenient than then the default tab searching at least extension supports shortcut key to invoke. How about vim navigation? In my situation, the behavior of `j` and `k` in firefox/chrome/chromium is page navigation. I have the idea to edit firefox's omni.ja to change the behavior of `j` and `k`, but I think it will become invalid if firefox is upgraded. I don't want to edit it again and again.